# Size of the quotient of a Gorenstein ring with an ideal generated by a regular sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, gorenstein

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local Gorenstein domain of dimension $2$ with finite residue field, let $x_1,x_2$ be a regular sequence in $R$.

Is it true that $R/(x_1,x_2)$ is finite?

Comment: Hint: For any Noetherian local ring $(R,m)$ and any regular element $a \in m$, $\dim{R/aR}=\dim{R}-1$.

Comment: Ok, applying this fact two times we obtain that $R/(x_1,x_2)$ has dimension $0$, hence it is Artinian. This implies that any descending chain of ideals must stabilize. I take the chain  $\mathfrak{m}\supseteq \mathfrak{m}^2\supseteq\dots$. This chain stabilizes, and it stabilizes to $0$ by Nakayama's lemma. All quotients of subsequent elements in the chain are f.g. vector spaces over $R/\mathfrak{m}$, hence they are finite. Hence we are done. Right?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: Thankyou! So it seems that the Gorenstein property is useless: this is true whenever we find a regular sequence (of length equal to the dimension of the ring) in a local noetherian ring.

Comment: That’s correct as well. Note however that we cannot always find such a regular sequence – it’s basically equivalent for the local ring to be Cohen-Macaulay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post an answer following the comments.

It is known (see e.g. Corollary 11.18 of Atiyah, MacDonald, "Commutative algebra") that the quotient of a local Noetherian ring with a non zero divisor has dimension equal to the dimension of the ring minus one. Therefore, $R/(x_1,x_2)$ has dimension $0$, hence it is an Artinian local ring. This implies that the descending chain of ideals $\mathfrak{m}\supseteq\mathfrak{m}^2\supseteq\dots$ must stabilize. By Nakayama's lemma, this sequence stabilizes to $0$. Also, all quotients of subsequent elements in the chain are finitely generated vector spaces over $R/\mathfrak{m}$, that is finite field. Therefore we have a finite chain
\begin{equation*}
     R\supseteq\mathfrak{m}\supseteq \mathfrak{m}^2\supseteq\dots\supseteq \mathfrak{m}^e=\{0\}
 \end{equation*}
where all quotients of subsequent elements are finite. This implies that $R$ is finite.